# C# IndexOutOfRangeException while accessing datas in array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I have the following code :

```
String[] enteteSplit = new String[48];
enteteSplit = entete.Split(';');
enteteSplit[35] = enteteSplit[35].Replace(',', '.');
```

Where entete is a string.
The 3rd line is throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException and i couldn't resolve this, any ideas ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, it appears there are less than 36 items in `enteteSplit`.

Comment: `enteteSplit` has less than 36 items in it.  Your first line doesn't matter since `Split()` just returns a new array.

Comment: I also tried doing :
String[] enteteSplit = entete.Split(';');
enteteSplit[35] = enteteSplit[35].Replace(',', '.');

And i checked that 'entete' had more than 35 ';' and it is still not working. I also checked that 'enteteSplit[35]' had something in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call this line

```
enteteSplit = entete.Split(';');
```

you are effectively creating an array that contains no more 48 elements but just the elements obtained splitting the string at the semicolon character.

So if your string is

```
entete = "test;test1;test2";
enteteSplit = entete.Split(';');
```

the resulting array has only 3 elements and thus trying to reach the 35th element causes the IndexOutOfRange Exception

You need to introduce a safety check here

```
if(enteteSplit.Length > 35)
   enteteSplit[35] = enteteSplit[35].Replace(',', '.');
```

Comment: It seems that adding the safety check has resolved my problem. Thank you :)